# JSF Bean-creation failed

Tags: mysql, activiti

I'm trying to use a mysql-database for Activiti BMPN.
For the Configurations I refer to the Activiti Guide.

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

</bean>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/activiti" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="processEngineConfiguration"
    class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
    <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="true" />
</bean>
```

The corresponding jar-files are located in: /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/..
(commons-dbcp-1.4.jar)

If I try to compile my project, I will get some error messages.

> 13:40:46,696 SEVERE [org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngines] (MSC service thread 1-3) Exception while initializing process engine :Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfiguration' defined in resource loaded through InputStream: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in resource loaded through InputStream: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/ObjectPool: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfiguration' defined in resource loaded through InputStream: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in resource loaded through InputStream: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/ObjectPool

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

From error message - You are missing Class

```
org.apache.commons.pool.ObjectPool
```

from classpath.

It can be found in commons-pool.jar library. It can be found in
[Project Home page](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/)
[Maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.6)